# Meaning of "I'm so excited I could crush a grape"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I read this on a sports website, where a fan is welcoming a new signing in their team.

I assume this means one is really excited, but what is the meaning of "*crush a grape*" - does it imply opening a bottle of champagne? or some test of physical strength?

Comment: I've never heard this phrase before, but is it possible to get some context for where you found this?

Comment: on a football website, a fan has written to welcome a new signing in their team.

Comment: Yes, can you please add that bit of the message to your question?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, "Oooh, I could crush a grape" was the catchphrase of Stu Francis, a British comedian and lead presenter on the children's show *Crackerjack*. As an American, I've never heard of Stu Francis, and Crackerjack to me is a delicious popcorn-based snack. Therefore, I don't know whether (or why) this is what's being referenced by that fan. It might, however, be a fruitful area of research.

Comment: @Nicholas: you might be on to something, all the references i see are in British English.

Comment: I think it was used ironically ie. the speaker was underwhelmed.

Comment: I simply couldn't stand this catchphrase as a kid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It came from the children's tv show Crackerjack, in which a man called Stu Francis used to shout [catchphrases,:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crackerjack_%28TV_series%29)

> Stu Francis also did a stand-up routine on occasion, using such catchphrases as "Ooh I Could Crush A Grape/Jump Off A Doll`s House" etc.

also

> Stu Francis (born 1951, Bolton, Lancashire, England) is a British comedian with a camp style of delivery who achieved celebrity as lead presenter on the children's television programme Crackerjack (1979–1984), on which his catchphrase was "Ooh! I could crush a grape".

This show was really popular, so  "I'm so excited I could crush a grape." became in common use, basically meaning "I'm really excited", and the rest was just for comedy.

N.B., other catchphrases from *Crackerjack* include:

> “Ooh, I could crush a grape/rip a tissue/pummel a peach”),

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some debate as to whether 'I could crush a grape' was used to mean 'I'm genuinely excited' or 'I'm supposed to be excited about this but I'm underwhelmed'. As it was used in a children's show watched also by adults, I would suggest that the children would assume the former but the real meaning for the adults was the latter. For the background see 
http://www.hulldailymail.co.uk/don-t-mind-remembered-crush-grape-man/story-11949409-detail/story.html

Comment: The link no longer works, and this is why we try and tell users to write a summary  or quote a few lines IN their answers instead of just adding a  link.

Answer (score 1):

In "The Code of the Woosters" by P.G. Woodhouse (first published in 1938), Stiffy Byng tells Bertram Wooster “*[I'm so happy I could bite a grape](https://books.google.it/books?id=fBPP0bhoLnMC&pg=PT100&dq=%22I%27m%20so%20happy%20I%20could%20bite%20a%20grape%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH852h9MziAhWHY1AKHVDKBkAQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=%22I'm%20so%20happy%20I%20could%20bite%20a%20grape%22&f=false)*” about her upcoming wedding and it doesn't seem like she's underwhelmed.

Answer (score 1):

I remember hearing the phrase as: “I feel so strong, I could crush a grape!” Most likely from Frankie Howerd, Ken Dodd or Larry Grayson.

Comment: All of whom were British comedians (I use the term loosely) from the 1960s and 70s

Comment: Bobby Ball of Cannon and Ball ('80s-'90s) used to exclaim it when excited.

Answer (score 0):

If you were brought up in about the 70s-80s in the UK you'd know the phrase very well - it's one of those phrases that was brought to popularity by a TV show of that era - kind of like "Lovely Jubbly" came into existence due to Only Fools and Horses or "Nice to see you to see you... Nice!" from The Generation Game.

Many shows have their own catchphrases which were introduced by the various presenters and some of them are remembered for years - the crush a grape one came from Crackerjack and even now - many years since Crackerjack finished it's still sometimes mentioned - although it would be more well known to people from the UK who watched Children's TV in the 80s or who were introduced to the phrase by their parents.

To "Crush a grape" just means to be really overly excited about something!

Comment: @Joachim The answer is explained beautifully though, provides similar (now outdated) examples  and adds further context.

Comment: "Lovely Jubbly" predates Only Fools and Horses. John Sullivan did not invent words and phrases, he used the ones he knew to create his characters who were exaggerated and aggregate versions of people he knew. "Cushty" sounds made up but is actually Romany.